# WordPress 404 text above the header

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem if you check the image link that i gave below there is a 404 text above the header does anyone have any idea what is it and how to fix it?

i already check the source code but didn't find any 404 text.

here is the image url http://i.gyazo.com/7bda64ce7ea0ca3825473a10427f3d73.png

here's the website url http://shorttermrentalsinbcs.com/

Comment: check your header.php file of your theme.

Comment: check you code. use ctrl+f option and type "404", you will find the text that you are trying to find.

Comment: hmm.. like i said already check the source code and don't fine any 404 text.. also my WP_DEBUG in wp-config.php is not activated

Answer (score 0):

found out that there's a 404 text inside my custom-function.php never thought of that in the first place until i search all files

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Brent Worden: This does provide an answer. "Where is the 404 text in my theme coming from?" "I found it, it was here"